# NoSuchElement exception in selenium with phantomjs

Tags: java, selenium, headless-browser

When i run the java code using the headless browser phatomjs ,am getting this error ,please help me to solve this ?

getting the below error

```
phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
```

Software 
Jar file version:`Phatomjsdriver:1.2.1`
exe version:`phantomjs-2.1.1-windows`
IDE:Eclipse
programming language:`java`

code i am executing -

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", phatomPath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("-incognito");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);


driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);

driver.get("https://www.*********.com/home.html?product=testCard");

String strPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println("Page title: - "+strPageTitle);


WebElement nameInputField = driver.findElement(By.id("card"));  
nameInputField.sendKeys("*************");

 driver.findElement(By.id("go")).click();

try{
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        //WebElement tableElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("reportTable")));
        WebElement tableElement = driver.findElement(By.className("reportTable"));
        System.out.println("taleElemen"+tableElement);
        java.util.List<WebElement> rows = tableElement.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        for (WebElement row : rows) {
            java.util.List<WebElement> cols = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            for (WebElement col : cols) {
                testData.put(col.getText().split(":")[0],col.getText().split(":")[1]);
            }       
        }


        WebElement avlBalance = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='Available Gift Card Balance']/../td[last()]"));
        testData.put("Available Gift Card Balance",avlBalance.getText());
        //lstSting.add(avlBalance.getText());
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

I have tried this capabilities as well -

```
caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(
            PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
            phatomPath2
        );
```

one more exception i am getting is -

```
phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
 org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name 'reportTable'","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"44","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:4857","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_77)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"class name\",\"value\":\"reportTable\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/d8e8c560-2bb4-11e6-b5f6-ddcaaac0831c/element"}}
    Command duration or timeout: 678 milliseconds
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
    System info: host: 'IBM207-PC09G4SD', ip: '9.195.87.191', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to call to the click method this way -

I used given code because for me `name` and `div id` (*go*)were same.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("go"));
        try {
            safeJavaScriptClick(element);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Method -

```
public static void safeJavaScriptClick(WebElement element) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (element.isEnabled() && element.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("Clicking on element with using java script click");

                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unable to click on element");
            }
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.out.println("Element is not attached to the page document " + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Element was not found in DOM " + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to click on element " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
```

This is the common error which will not harm our current execution.

```
 phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
```

To check something on clicked page we need to do -

```
    WebElement tableElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("reportTable")));
```

This perfectly worked for me.